# WebService timeout

Tags: asp.net, time, service, out

I deployed one webservice which calls function which going take more than 5 -6 hours. I am using this webservice on my asp.net page and I am calling this webservice asynchronously. So how should I increase webservice time out?

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling a function that takes 5-6 hours to complete, you may want to re-think your architecture. Would a user sit on the page and wait 5 or 6 hours for your process to finish? Probably not. Maybe you could have your web service set an indicator in a database, xml file or some other data store when it has completed. Then, in your asp.net page, you can click a button or complete some other action to check that indicator to see if the process has finished.

Comment: See in my scenario from asp.net page I am just triggering webservice by passing some parameters to webservice. And in webservice it take parameters and execute its functionality and update in db. So I am able to close asp.net page anytime once webservice call is made. My problem some times webservice runs successfulyy with updaintg db and some time it not able to update db and I am sure that code to write in db is perfect one so is there any scenario where webservice do its own timeout and how I can configure it?

Comment: So, the asp page really doesn't care if the job fails, but you do? Why not have the web service send you an Email or something if it fails?

Answer (score 2):

You need to chance the executionTimout in your Web.Config to something large like :

executionTimeout unit is in seconds.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="21600"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with all requests in your webservice having a long timeout, you can set

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"/>
```

Under

```
<system.web>
```

in your web.config, where 300 is your timeout in seconds

However, as [DevSlick answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045573/webservice-timeout/5045655#5045655), you may want to reconsider your archetecture, web services aren't meant for long running tasks, you may want to create a console application that runs on a schedule.

Comment: As I am calling webservice asynchrnously so I am able to close asp.net page suddenly request get submitted. But my problem is weather there is any time out property for webservice so that it can able to handle any function for long time...